# Merge two JSON object with Underscore.js

Tags: json, node.js, underscore.js

I'm trying to merge the following 2 JSON object which is Youtube API response. I've tried

```
_.values(_.extend(_.indexBy(array1, 'kind'), _.indexBy(array2, 'kind')))
```

but it doesn't merge properly. I've tried _.flatten, _.union, _.defaults but none of them work for me.

1

```
{ kind: 'youtube#playlistItem',
       etag: '"kuL0kDMAqRo3pU7O0pwlO-Lfzp4/tGxY5umSWnuSkk1adS4H8nsd7nI"',
       id: 'PLhAf_GEuRunTjOdIMNbFsPSMLcbkw3RoTqruH97SaMEs',
       snippet: 
        { publishedAt: '2015-12-13T12:16:47.000Z',
          channelId: 'UCwy6X3JB24VTsDFqMwdO5Jg',
          title: 'John Hockenberry: We are all designers',
          description: 'http://www.ted.com Journalist John Hockenberry tells a personal story inspired by a pair of flashy wheels in a wheelchair-parts catalogue -- and how they showed him the value of designing a life of intent. (From The Design Studio session at TED2012, guest-curated by Chee Pearlman and David Rockwell.)\n\nTEDTalks is a daily video podcast of the best talks and performances from the TED Conference, where the world\'s leading thinkers and doers give the talk of their lives in 18 minutes. Featured speakers have included Al Gore on climate change, Philippe Starck on design, Jill Bolte Taylor on observing her own stroke, Nicholas Negroponte on One Laptop per Child, Jane Goodall on chimpanzees, Bill Gates on malaria and mosquitoes, Pattie Maes on the "Sixth Sense" wearable tech, and "Lost" producer JJ Abrams on the allure of mystery. TED stands for Technology, Entertainment, Design, and TEDTalks cover these topics as well as science, business, development and the arts. Closed captions and translated subtitles in a variety of languages are now available on TED.com, at http://www.ted.com/translate\n\nIf you have questions or comments about this or other TED videos, please go to http://support.ted.com',
          thumbnails: 
           { default: 
              { url: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ti_i-M3pk5M/default.jpg',
                width: 120,
                height: 90 },
             medium: 
              { url: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ti_i-M3pk5M/mqdefault.jpg',
                width: 320,
                height: 180 },
             high: 
              { url: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ti_i-M3pk5M/hqdefault.jpg',
                width: 480,
                height: 360 },
             standard: 
              { url: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ti_i-M3pk5M/sddefault.jpg',
                width: 640,
                height: 480 },
             maxres: 
              { url: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ti_i-M3pk5M/maxresdefault.jpg',
                width: 1280,
                height: 720 } },
          channelTitle: 'Seong Lee',
          playlistId: 'PLy7hFLa6kbitaVkEcgPEt6GlfVjuyO91K',
          position: 30,
          resourceId: { kind: 'youtube#video', videoId: 'ti_i-M3pk5M' } },
       contentDetails: { videoId: 'ti_i-M3pk5M' } },
}
```

2

```
{ kind: 'youtube#videoListResponse',
    etag: '"kuL0kDMAqRo3pU7O0pwlO-Lfzp4/BQsUkCeR_vYw5Am_P0zDQ65R2RI"',
    pageInfo: { totalResults: 1, resultsPerPage: 1 },
    items: 
     [ { kind: 'youtube#video',
         etag: '"kuL0kDMAqRo3pU7O0pwlO-Lfzp4/63882pNOoZMxxAveXDjjDGxrL6g"',
         id: 'ti_i-M3pk5M',
         contentDetails: 
          { duration: 'PT19M44S',
            dimension: '2d',
            definition: 'hd',
            caption: 'true',
            licensedContent: true } },
       [length]: 1 ] }
```

Comment: I haven't looked at underscore on how to do this, but you could try using vanilla javascript `Object.assign({}, object1, object2)`. Duplicate keys will get overriden. Hope this helps.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: So I will have multiple set of these and I want them to be merged like 
a { [1] [2] }, b { [1] [2] }, c { [1] [2] } ... hopefully without duplicated data with merge.

Comment: { [1] [2] } this is not a valid Obj definition in JS.  we can not use any array without key in obj.  is this correct? { 1: {..}, 2: {...} }

Comment: @risyasin Please disregard the syntax that I gave. 
This is probably more close. a: { 1: {..}, 2: {..} }, b: { 1: {..}, 2: {..} }. c: { 1: {..}, 2: {..} } ...

Comment: a: { 1: {..}, 2: {..} }. Ok now can you make "a" & repeating list item's contents clear?  because your jsons are different types. playlistItem & videoListResponse.